# How identityserver3 token can be protected

Tags: identityserver3

Could you please help me to clarify token related questions?

1. I have implemented HTTPS all the way through, my question is that
   when token is granted I can see it under the Chrome developer tool
   and the redirection url, which means if someone hacked my computer
   they can use it too? I have checked the Fiddler and I can't see the
   token from there.
2. The web api has CORS implemented, it works fine in the browsers as
   origins that are not listed will get requests denied. The problem is
   that I retrieved the access token from Chrome, used Fiddler to
   compose a request and that worked fine, it got around the CORS check
   and returned the results, I expected to have the request denied.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. yes
2. CORS only applies to browsers and AJAX requests